# add empty src folder to GIT repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

i want to add an empty SRC folder to GIT repository, is there possibility that i can add without having any files inside initially, but i will definitely have files in future. i want this because when my team import the project i want them to have src folder, so that they can add files in future.

i have [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) but is there anyways that i can add empty folder.

```
git add SRC
```

command is not working for me

Comment: The question you linked too and it's answers are still valid.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do this.  You will need to add some sort of file, such as a README or a hidden file (some people use `.gitkeep` as a convention, though I prefer README which can explain what the folder is for).